# Playing .mp4 file in android programatically from dropbox or googledrive

Tags: google-drive-api, android-mediaplayer, dropbox-api

Is it possible to call and play .mp4 file  in android programatically from dropbox or googledrive?

Answer (score 0):

For the Dropbox API, yes, you can either download the file using the /files (GET) call:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET

Or, to stream the file, you can get a streamable link for it using the /media call:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media

You can then pass the file or URL to whatever media player you're using, e.g., [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)/[VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)